# Change spaces with underscore in filename

Tags: bash, macos, replace, command, filenames

I have a multiples files with space, and I want replace this for a underscore with command line (Mac)

xxx xxx.jpg -> xxx_xxx.jpg

It's possible with only line command?

Answer (score 20):

For all files in current directory

```
for i in *;do mv "$i" "${i// /_}";done
```

If you only want to match files with spaces (to prevent tons of error messages when it tries to move files into themselves) though you could use extended glob

```
shopt -s extglob
for i in +(* *);do mv "$i" "${i// /_}";done
```

Comment: @Inian Who said anything was wrong with it? It hasn't been downvoted?

Comment: Upvote for utilizing Bash's built-in regex abilities instead of piping through to something else. Nice!

Comment: Please always use `mv -i` to avoid accidental overwritten files in bulk moves!